# Can not load pb file in tensorflow serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have used SavedModel (Inception_resnet_v2) to export the TensorFlow model files and use TensorFlow Serving to load the files.I have directly replaced offical minst saved_model.pb with my own Inception_resnet_v2 saved_model.pb file. But I got one error.

`deep@ubuntu:~/serving$ bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_name=mnist --model_base_path=/home/deep/serving/tmp/mnist_model
2017-06-18 10:39:41.963490: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/main.cc:146] Building single TensorFlow model file config:  model_name: mnist model_base_path: home/deep/serving/tmp/mnist_model model_version_policy: 0
2017-06-18 10:39:41.963752: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:375] Adding/updating models.
2017-06-18 10:39:41.963762: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:421]  (Re-)adding model: mnist
2017-06-18 10:39:42.065556: I tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:698] Successfully reserved resources to load servable {name: mnist version: 1}
2017-06-18 10:39:42.065610: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:66] Approving load for servable version {name: mnist version: 1}
2017-06-18 10:39:42.065648: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:74] Loading servable version {name: mnist version: 1}
2017-06-18 10:39:42.065896: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/bundle_shim.cc:360] Attempting to load native SavedModelBundle in bundle-shim from: /home/deep/serving/tmp/mnist_model/1
2017-06-18 10:39:42.066130: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:226] Loading SavedModel from: /home/deep/serving/tmp/mnist_model/1
2017-06-18 10:39:42.080775: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:274] Loading SavedModel: fail. Took 14816 microseconds.
2017-06-18 10:39:42.080822: E tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:38] Loading servable: {name: mnist version: 1} failed: Not found: Could not find meta graph def matching supplied tags.`

What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I chatted to the Serving engineers, and here are some of their thoughts on this:

> Looks like they need to specify a tag either in the saved model, or on
>   the command line. (log line of note: failed: Not found: Could not find
>   meta graph def matching supplied tags. )
>
> It looks like the SavedModel loader is unable to find a graph
>   corresponding to the tags they have supplied. Here is some
>   documentation:
>   https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model#tags
>
> Ah, to add: They could use the SavedModel CLI to inspect the model and
>   see what tag-sets are available. Here is the documentation for that:
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/programmers_guide/saved_model_cli.
>
> They can run
>
> ```
>     saved_model_cli show --dir <SavedModelDir>
> ```
>
> to check what tag-sets are in the SavedModel if they have pip
>   installed tensorflow.